# Difference between TokenAuthentication and OAuth (specifically in Django REST)

Tags: reactjs, authentication, oauth, oauth-2.0, django-rest-framework

Reading up on the types of authentication which I plan to implement on a Django Backend and a React FrontEnd.

Was just wondering if the "TokenAuthentication" in the Django REST framework in

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/

is entirely different to the OAuth2.0 Authentication Library that they are recommending? See http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#django-oauth-toolkit

I know obviously, it could very well be different but as of now, my understanding is that they are both token based authentication

a token is generated by the server > stored on the client > validated by the server if client does another request

OAuth2.0 may have additional security but I want to make sure if I am understanding the two correctly.

UPDATED question:

I'm thinking maybe, TokenAuthentication is a better way of handling internal logins while OAuth is only if you want other apps to access your data through my users?

Cheers